# Getting number of records printed issues in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS Reports with 2 groups

GroupParent (State)  with totals = CountDistinct(Fields!fieldFromDataset.Value) this is working OK

GroupChild (techname) for the same field Fields!fieldFromDataset.Value

I need to add a Final Total with the sum of all number of rows printed in each groupchild

```
State   techname
================ 
NSW     techname1
        techname2
total NSW 2 techs

QLD     techname1
        techname3
        techname4 
total QLD 3 techs
```

Final Total 5 techs   ----> I can't use same expression because there are some records with the same techname in different states

I create another column to show the result of expression `CountDistinct(Fields!fieldFromDataset.Value)` for each group Parent that is show me the right value. but I can't use this reportItems! variable in a SUM()

Answer (score 0):

Is there 1 row per GroupChild row in the report? If so you could use the expression CountRows("GroupChild") assuming GroupChild is the name of that row group.

Comment: I tried to use it but can't use this expression in the Parent total group. I got error "Yhe value expression for the text boxt has scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.

Comment: Oh, bummer. Have you tried playing around a bit with the InScope function? I would try something such as Sum(Iif(InScope("GroupChild"), 1, 0))